# annotate result not included in Json response

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I want to count votes as per Model, and its working fine when i test this query in Django shell but when passing as a **json** i cannot see the column **total_votes** when i get **Json Response**.

```
class Model(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)



class ModelVote(models.Model):
    model = models.ForeignKey(Model, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.BooleanField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

```
from django.core.serializers import serialize


class ModelList(View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        
        models = Model.objects.annotate(total_votes=Count('modelvote'))

        return HttpResponse(serialize("json", models), content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query solved my issue of total_votes not passing as Json Response. just adding `.values()` worked.

`Model.objects.annotate(total_votes=Count('modelvote')).values()`

`return JsonResponse({'models': list(models)}, status=200)`

Answer (score 1):

This is a known limitation of the serialization framework

http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5711